# Proving an inequality (proof-verification)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification

In an assignment I was asked to prove this equality

$||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

**My proof:**

$||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$

$\iff||x|-|y||+|y|\leq |x-y|+|y|$

$\iff ||x|-|y|+|y||\leq |x-y|+|y|$

$\iff |x|\leq |x-y|+|y|$

$\iff |(x-y)+y|\leq |x-y|+|y|$

which is the triangle inequality $\square$

---

Someone said to me that this proof is only partially correct. However, I can't find my mistake (if there is any).

So, is this proof legit or not?

Comment: @NP-hard: Ok, I think I see my mistake. I guess the second $\iff$ is incorrect? It looked correct to me, at first.

Comment: @NP-hard: Now my question is: Is there a way to prove the inequality the way I tried to do, or is it a dead end because of the second $\iff$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By triangle inequality, we have
$$
|x| \leq |x - y| + |y| \Rightarrow |x| - |y| \leq |x - y|
$$
and
$$
|y| \leq |y - x| + |x| \Rightarrow |x| - |y| \geq -|x - y|
$$
Therefore,
$$
||x| - |y|| \leq |x - y|
$$

Comment: I tried to solve this too. Could one instead divide into cases |x|>|y| and |x|<= |y| and go from there?

Comment: @Adam Yes. If $|x| > |y|$, you only need to prove $|x| - |y| \leq |x - y|$; and if $|x| \leq |y|$, you only need to prove $|y| - |x| \leq |x - y|$.

Comment: May I ask how did you get the $|y|\leq |y-x|+|x|$?

Comment: @Arthur It is just the triangle inequality, $|a| + |b| \geq |a + b|$.

Comment: But what would be $a$ and $b$ in this case?

Comment: I do understand the first line though.

Comment: @Arthur $a$ is $y - x$ and $b$ is $x$.

Comment: I see, I forgot that $|x-y|$ and $|y-x|$ is the same.